# python launch.json in jetbrain fleet

Tags: python

I was trying to use jetbrain fleet and made a simple Hello World! but whenever I run the code fleet asks for configurations and I tried searching for a configuration and the only ones I found were **VSCode** configurations and when I tried them they didn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to this link:: **https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-python.html**

Basically if you enable smart mode it will help you. Otherwise configure run.json like done in this example
[image: example for python.]

to find python interpreter path on linux or macOS:

```
which python3
```